# How can I prevent angular from removing query parameters on production mode?

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring-boot, production

I'm building a web app for my job that uses angular 10 as frontend and Spring boot 2.2 for backend.
It's a very simple app with just one route, but this is route can receive a query parameter and show a different HTMLitem depending on the parameter
These are my routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
   {path:'mainapp', component: HomeComponent},
   {path: '', redirectTo: '/mainapp', pathMatch:'full'}
]
```

The app works great in development mode, I mean when I run my war file with java and then run ng serve, all is good

However, when I generate the production build, in the /resources/static folder so Spring boot can serve my angular app as a static site, there are some issues.

The first issue is when I try to navigate to localhost:8080:/?report=weekly, it redirects me to localhost:8080:/mainapp and removes my query parameter.
The second issue is when I try to navigate to either localhost:8080:/mainapp or localhost:8080:/mainapp?report=weekly it shows a Whitelabel error page with a 404 error code. Even when I refresh the site

I encountered a similar issue before when I tried to deploy an Angular app to a VPS, and at that time it worked for me to add a .htaccess file with a few commands, so I tried this as well here, this is the file I added:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

But apparently, this did not work. This file was added at the same level where my angular.json file is.

This is my project folder structure

[image]

I have the angular app in the Ui folder

I am not sure what else could I should you, but if you need any other information about my project let me know.

Also since this is a work-related project I can't upload the code directly, however, I'm trying to replicate the basic architecture to upload it to Github

Until then, can somebody point me in the right direction? How can I fix this route?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So after a couple of try and error seasons, I managed to make this work by adding a controller that redirects to my index

```
@Controller
public class ViewController {
   @RequestMapping("/mainapp")
   public String index(){
      return "forward:/index.html";
   } 

 }
```

Just in case someone else is having the same issue